# Seeking balanced combination of fast, terse, and legible code to add up values from an array of objects

Tags: powershell

Given the following array of objects:

```
Email               Domain       Tally
-----               -----        -----
email1@domainA.com  domainA.com  4
email1@domainB.com  domainB.com  1
email2@domainC.com  domainC.com  6
email4@domainA.com  domainA.com  1
```

I'd like to "group by" Domain and add up Tally as I go. The end result would like this:

```
Domain       Tally
------       -----
domainA.com  5
domainB.com  1
domainC.com  6
```

I have something that works but I feel like it's overly complicated.

```
$AllTheAddresses = Get-AllTheAddresses

$DomainTally = @()
foreach ($Addy in $AllTheAddresses)
{
    if ($DomainTally | Where-Object {$_.RecipientDomain -eq $Addy.RecipientDomain})
    {
        $DomainTally |
            Where-Object {$_.RecipientDomain -eq $Addy.RecipientDomain} |
            ForEach-Object {$_.Tally += $Addy.Tally }
    }
    else
    {
        $props = @{
            RecipientDomain = $Addy.RecipientDomain
            Tally = $Addy.Tally
        }
        $DomainTally += New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property $props
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my example, I'm creating the addresses as hashtables, but PowerShell will let you refer to the keys by `.Property` similar to an object.

If you're truly just summing by the Domain, then it seems like you don't need anything more complicated than a HashTable to create your running total.

The basic summation:

```
$Tally = @{}
$AllTheAddresses | ForEach-Object {
    $Tally[$_.Domain] += $_.Tally
}
```

Using this sample data...

```
$AllTheAddresses = @( 
    @{ Email = "email1@domainA.com"; Domain = "domainA.com"; Tally = 4 };
    @{ Email = "email1@domainB.com"; Domain = "domainB.com"; Tally = 1 };
    @{ Email = "email1@domainC.com"; Domain = "domainC.com"; Tally = 6 };
    @{ Email = "email1@domainA.com"; Domain = "domainA.com"; Tally = 1 }
    )
```

And you get this output:

```
PS> $tally
Name                           Value                                                                                    
----                           -----                                                                                    
domainC.com                    6                                                                                        
domainB.com                    1                                                                                        
domainA.com                    5
```

Comment: Thanks, @TravisEz13 - I was about to expand the alias, and I need to figure out that markup on the .Property.

Comment: Fast, terse, _and_ legible.  Win.

Comment: I've come up with `$Tally.Keys | % { Write-Host $_; $Tally.$_ }`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a "PowerShellic" version, notice the piping and flow of the data.
You could of course write this as a one liner (I did originally before I posted the answer here).  The 'better' part of this is using the Group-Object and Measure-Object cmdlets.  Notice there are no conditionals, again because the example uses the pipeline.

```
$AllTheAddresses | 
Group-Object -Property Domain |
ForEach-Object {
    $_ | 
    Tee-Object -Variable Domain |
    Select-Object -Expand Group |
    Measure-Object -Sum Tally |
    Select-Object -Expand Sum |
    ForEach-Object { 
        New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property @{
            'Domain' = $Domain.Name
            'Tally' = $_
        }
    } |
    Select-Object Domain, Tally
}
```

A more terse version

```
$AllTheAddresses | 
Group Domain |
% {
    $_ | 
    Tee-Object -Variable Domain |
    Select -Expand Group |
    Measure -Sum Tally |
    Select -Expand Sum |
    % { 
        New-Object PSObject -Property @{
            'Domain' = $Domain.Name
            'Tally' = $_
        }
    } |
    Select Domain, Tally
}
```

Comment: btw, I approved the edit to the above that added a lot of extra fluff :-)  BUT it did make it more readable.  If this were me in a pinch I'd probably use more aliases and default conventions for parameter passing.  But then it gets a bit cryptic for non-PowerShellers

Comment: To elaborate on proper coding for PowerShell.  You should run [PSScriptAnalyzer](https://github.com/PowerShell/PSScriptAnalyzer) on you scripts.  It would recommend these changes.  The first rule is to "[Avoid alias](https://github.com/PowerShell/PSScriptAnalyzer/blob/development/RuleDocumentation/AvoidAlias.md)".  The second is to "[Avoid using Positional Parameters](https://github.com/PowerShell/PSScriptAnalyzer/blob/development/RuleDocumentation/AvoidUsingPositionalParameters.md)".

Comment: Totally agree TravisEz13, it really depends if this will live in a script or it the OP is typing it once on the command line

Comment: @JoshPetitt I take all the blame for this but, with my skill level, this looks obfuscated to me. :( I have to get home now but I'll try this tomorrow. Seeing it in action should help my comprehension.

Answer (score 0):

`Group-Object` is definitely the way to go.

In the interest of terseness:

```
Get-AllTheAddresses |Group-Object Domain |Select-Object @{N='Domain';E={$_.Name}},@{N='Tally';E={($_.Group.Tally |Measure-Object).Sum}}
```

Comment: Are you seeing something in the question that I'm missing?  There's a lot of programmatic/execution overhead hidden in the details of your suggestion.

Comment: @MatthewWetmore Absolutely, and your solution will outperform mine on speed/overhead, without a trace of doubt. But the output sample OP shows implies a collection of objects with `Domain` and `Tally` properties, which your suggestion fails to produce :-)

Comment: Did you catch the point in my code where it uses both `.Tally` and `.Domain` properties from the original input?  My sample input mocks those properties using the HashTable, but the solution will work equally well with an object that has a `Tally` property or a HashTable that has a key by the same name.

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen I appreciate the adherence to my output but I think I have to go with Matthew Wetmore's answer. Thank you!

Comment: @MatthewWetmore Yes, I fully understand your code, but your resulting `$Tally` object is a hashtable (which may be totally acceptable for OP's use case). If you look at the desired formatted output in the question, it has a `Domain` and a `Tally` column, ie. the resulting objects have these properties - as does the result from my answer

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen, ah, that's the piece I was missing - knew there must be something.  I had `.Name` and `.Tally` My usual trick with that would be to create a PSObject as the value stored in the hashtable. The PSObject would have two NoteProperty set, one for Domain and one for Tally.  Thanks for the clarification!

Comment: @MatthewWetmore Anytime :) Casting with the `[PSCustomObject]` type accelerator would be most low-overhead in that case, but since you'd need to produce the hashtable in a separate statement (to do the `Tally` sum), you might end up with the properties in the wrong order (due to internal ordering of the hashtable keys), and have to reconstruct the hashtable literal - and then it's not especially terse anymore ^_^